# invoking a Bash script indirectly - and a puzzle about how to use `source` appropriately

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a script called `greeting_script` as follows:

```
GREETING='Top O the Morning to Ya!'
export GREETING
echo $GREETING
```

If I run this script from the command line, I see the following result:

```
> export GREETING='hello'
> echo $GREETING
hello
> source greeting_script
Top O the Morning to Ya!
> echo $GREETING
Top O the Morning to Ya!
```

This is what I expect.  I have another script called 'indirect_greeting_script' as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
source greeting_script
```

If I run this script from the command line, I see the following:

```
> export GREETING='hello'
> echo $GREETING
hello
> indirect_greeting_script
Top O the Morning to Ya!
> echo $GREETING
hello
```

Note that I have the permissions set on `indirect_greeting_script` in order to enable it to be executed directly at the command line.  I also have the first line that `#!/bin/bash`

Obviously when I invoke `greeting_script` indirectly the results are not being stored in my current environment properly.  I would like for the `indirect_greeting_script` to be an executable at the command line and not a file that I have to `source`.   What is it that I don't understand?

NOTE: it works as expected if I make `indirect_greeting_script` a normal file (i.e., not executable), remove the leading line that reads `#!/bin/bash` and invoke it with the `source` command.

Answer (score 2):

A child process cannot modify the environment of its parent. `export` simply marks a parameter to be included in the environment of any children processes. When you call it in your script, it does not cause the value to be sent back to the parent.

Comment: Apparently this is the case - but what do I do about it?

Comment: You would need to use some form of interprocess communication; having the child write to (and the parent read from) a temporary file is probably the simplest.

Comment: @JonCrowell: what you do about it depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish. Setting variables in a script you run without `source` (or its synonym `.`) will not affect your parent shell. period. But depending on what your real goal is, there might be some other way to accomplish it.

Comment: Another simple option is to have the child script print to standard output, and have the parent capture the output with `GREETING=$(child)`.